# query that returns both aggregated data as well as filtered documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  A: "number"
}
```

How to write a MongoDB aggregation pipeline that returns both:

1. the list of documents where `A > 100`
2. and the average of all the documents returned?

In other words, this query must return both the granular filtered documents and then a grouped statistic, which is the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [$facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage in the Aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "A": {
        "$gt": 100
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "list": [],
      "average": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "value": {
              "$avg": "$A"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gK6eOHXh449)

Comment: Consider duplicating the `$match` as a first stage as well to avoid the collection scan (assuming there is an index on the field and that the range condition is reasonably selective)

Comment: I think he wants average of all the documents, so `$match` as the first stage before the `$facet` would not work.

Comment: @NeNaD, actually no. I just want the average of the documents where A > 100. And yes, being able to use indexes is required.

Comment: I updated my answer and working example.